# Android: location of the an ImageView Changes on different sizes screen Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a game like app in which the user has to find different Objects within the given time.

All things are working on my mobile phone but the location of the objects change when I install the same game on a different device. Basically I have chosen a background image (background of the layout) and locate the different objects on it and have to hide the object in the specific location.

Their  position is different on different mobiles, I am using Eclipse and I have checked it using `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` and linear inside the relative and vice versa throw java  the code is given below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Probably you should consider this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Paste your layout file, please.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have tried Relative and Linear Layouts

Comment: I hve edited the question and provide the code as well

Comment: @SultanAli , did my answer help or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
```

you should use

```
android:layout_weight
```

the reason for this is because even if you change the orientation of your device, your app's layout will not stay consistant.
For example try something like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_c"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
```

this gaurantees that no matter what the screen size, both textviews will share the screen equally.

Comment: Interesting working
but if i have more then 20 Images to b placed in it and all the Images should be placed in the specific location then what should i do?

Comment: you can decrease and increase layout_weight values as you see fit, so instead of 0.5, you could have 0.1, depending on the number of items you want to fit to the screen, you should also declare android:wightSum on your root view, which specifies the total weight sum of the children

Comment: basically i want to place all object on the different location or you can say that i want to hide the image according the background picture where it would not be searched easily. Can you please give some suggestions or example code

Comment: Sbonelo Mbhamali please give me some suggestions

Comment: please any one else can help in this issue