# How can I fix this android layout for different resolutions?

Tags: android, layout

Layout Image :

http://s18.postimg.org/kihvabse1/Capture.jpg

given above is an android interface that I created When I change the emulator(phone model) the interface wont adjust according to the model I select how can I fix it.currently I have designed for a phone of 1280x720 resolution.

XML Code:

```
<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

     <GridLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical"  />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="119dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_row="6"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_row="10"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_row="10"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_row="10"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_row="12"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_row="13"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" />


    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: please refer this android developers link [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: maybe this can help you [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497033/android-location-of-the-an-imageview-changes-on-different-sizes-screen-android/28501277#28501277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of child

```
 GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
 params.width = (parent.getWidth()/parent.getColumnCount()) -params.rightMargin - params.leftMargin;
 child.setLayoutParams(params);
```